# SQL Recursive Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a column that contains all cities of the referenced addresses.

```
DECLARE @AddressList nvarchar(max)
SELECT @AddressList = COALESCE(@AddressList + ' ', '') + City  FROM [Address]

SELECT
    Employee.*, 
    (SELECT @AddressList) AS AddressCities
FROM Employee
```

But I dont know where to put the WHERE clause.

```
...
    (SELECT @AddressList WHERE EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId) AS AddressCities
...
```

The above test doesnt work..

Table schemas are:

> **Employee**
>   EmployeeId
>   Name
>
> **Address**
>   Street
>   City
>   EmployeeId

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of the table schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you wish to show all *Cities* in a single column for the employee. So you wish to *GROUP BY and CONCAT*.

Using Sql Server 2005, try this *(working example)*

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE(
        EmployeeId INT,
        NAME VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Employee (EmployeeId,[NAME]) SELECT 1, 'A'
INSERT INTO @Employee (EmployeeId,[NAME]) SELECT 2, 'B'

DECLARE @Address TABLE(
        Street VARCHAR(50),
        City VARCHAR(50),
        EmployeeId INT
)

INSERT INTO @Address (Street,City, EmployeeId) SELECT 'A','A', 1
INSERT INTO @Address (Street,City, EmployeeId) SELECT 'B','B', 1
INSERT INTO @Address (Street,City, EmployeeId) SELECT 'C','C', 1
INSERT INTO @Address (Street,City, EmployeeId) SELECT 'D','D', 2
INSERT INTO @Address (Street,City, EmployeeId) SELECT 'E','E', 2
INSERT INTO @Address (Street,City, EmployeeId) SELECT 'F','F', 2


SELECT  e.EmployeeId,
        e.[NAME],
        (
            SELECT  al.City + ','
            FROM    @Address al
            WHERE   al.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
FROM    @Employee e
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId,
        e.[NAME]
```

Comment: +1 XML PATH is easiest way to do this if you want to, if you don't undertand why it's ok to just use 'as is'

Answer (score 0):

Do need more information about what you mean by 'column that contains all cities'. How is what you want different to the following might help you phrase the question

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId,e.Name,a.City
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Address a ON a.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId,e.Name
```

-- update

I think I see what you mean, do you want like:

```
EmployeeID | Name | Address
1          | John | 'London','Paris','Rome'
2          | Jane | 'New York','Miami'
```

?